# How to provide a mock interface to Autofac in AspNet Core integration testing?

Tags: c#, integration-testing, autofac, xunit

I have a web api project that I'm trying to integration test. The controller is:

```
[Route("hello")]
public sealed class MyController : Controller
{
   private readonly IFoo _foo;

   public MyController(IFoo foo)
   {
      _foo = foo;
   }

   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult Hello()
   {
       _foo.MethodToVerify();
       return Ok("Foo");
   }
}
```

`IFoo` is registered in the WebApi using Autofac in `ContainerBuilder` (builder) like

```
public void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<FooImplementation>()
           .WithAnotherInterface(builder, "hello")
           .As<IFoo>();
}
```

Where `WithAnotherInterface(string)` is an extension method like:

```
public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> WithAnotherInterface<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>(this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> reg, ContainerBuilder builder, string val)
  : where TReflectionActivatorData : ReflectionActivatorData
{
    builder.RegisterType<AnotherInterfaceImplementation>()
           .Named<IAnotherInterface>("another")
           .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IErrorHandler>(val))
           .AutoActivate()
           .SingleInstance();

    return registration;
}
```

Now in my test, I'm doing this:

```
public class MyTest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    MyTest(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _foo = Mock.Of<IFoo>();
        _factory = factory;

        _client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                  {
                       builder.ConfigureTestContainer<ContainerBuilder>(b =>
                       {
                           b.Register(ctx => _foo).SingleInstance().As<IFoo>();
                       });
                  })
                  .CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
       var res = await _client.GetAsync("hello");

       var mock = Mock.Get(_foo);

       mock.Verify(v => v.MethodToVerify(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

However, my verification is failing and recorded performed invocations are zero.

Comment: you forgot to include `_service` definition and initialization.

Comment: @MatJ Sorry, it was a typo. Supposed to be `_foo`.

Comment: Also, `b.Register(ctx => _foo).SingleInstance().As<IChatGroupService>();` should be `As<IFoo>()` right?

Comment: Why is WithAnotherInterface an extension method that doesn't do anything with the registration? Seems complicated.

Comment: @Travis Illig, yes I agree. Unfortunately changing this is not an option. At least not for the time being as the programmer who passed me this code feels that this is the best way to do it.